# computer can't run even low graphics games or browse web properly

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure

system specification

I have got an amd athlon X2 64bit 5200+ processor along with asus m2n-mx-se-plus motherboard,2 gb ram,1gb ddr3 amd radeon 5450 graphics card and 160 gb seagate hardisk.

problem

1 month before i could play high graphics games like nfs run,assassins creed black flag,elder scroll vs skyrim etc games without any serious lag.While playing these games my cpu would hit around 60 degree celsius as well as gpu.
Recently one day morning i couldn't run high graphics games like the way it used to.There were serious lags with all those games that worked fine previously.Even low graphics games like IGI,medal of honor was lagging.Also now temperature of my cpu and gpu doesn't exceed 48 degree even when i am playing.Even,when i scroll down while browsing a web page,there is a heavy lag.Plus the psu was damaged once after this problem and was changed.

I changed the heat sink 1 week before and couldn't observe any change.Also i tried overclocking my processor but that too didn't help.Is there any solution to this other than changing the hardware?And which part of the system is possibly damaged?

**Computer back to full speed but for some time (recently)**
Recently computer came back to full speed but it doesn't work at that speed for much long,say for some 2 or 3 hrs.I ran the benchmark test when system was slow and when it was normal.

[benchmark result at normal speed](http://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/1358988)

[benchmark result at low speed](http://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/1344440)

note:both test were run with the same no:of background processes.Though the variation in background cpu usage seems to be way too different in both these results.(does it mean the processor is the issue.I think so)

Comment: I find it doubtful you could play Assassin Creed Black Flag and Skyrim with only 1 GB of memory

Comment: Most of these components seem unlikely to ever run those games. That CPU is a dual core from 2008 and only supports DDR2 and 2GB RAM is barely enough to run Windows on its own.

Comment: that machine does not come close to half the *minimum* specifications for those games.

Comment: @Ramhound that is the reason why i don't really want to change my hardware.I played almost every game in assassins creed series except unity and syndicate(which will not possibly run)

Comment: The hardware you describe simply isn't capable of running those programs.

Comment: @Ramhound i never believe in the minimum system requirement for a  game(i am not an expert in computer but i find that in android phones its not the spec that only matter.A perfect combination of the hardwares can only make it top of the class.I know this can't be compared with the case of computers).I swear these things did work although black flag was a bit slow.Atleast if i am right this pc is good enough for browsing web right?Even scrolling down a webpage is difficult and slow.Its like almost everything has become equally slow.Be it a low graphics or high graphics game or even browsing.

Comment: I had a similar situation where my hard drive started to go bad - everything hiccuped with lag, yet nothing outright stopped working. Try running check disk and mem test to see if anything is up with your hard drive or RAM.

Comment: @Gary chkdsk didn't show any problem and how to run memory test.I had also run the benchark test at www.userbenchmark.com and found that my processor,ram are way below the expectation.....but now the computer seems to have picked up the normal speed.But it lasts for some hours only,after which its back to the slow state.I did ran benchmark test when it got to normal speed and found that cpu,ram and hdd are working way above expectation.......i really don't know what is happening

Comment: did you run **chkdsk /R c:**.  The standard check just check the headers and not the whole disk.

Comment: use ASUS probe or speed fan to check the voltages from the power supply, when its going slow, to make sure the 3.3,5, and 12V are all +/- 5% of stated values.  Fans die slowly and stop and start randomly near death, when the system slows down check your fan make sure they are running normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.The issue was the motherboard.It was struck by lightning though it wasn't completely damaged.Maybe some components inside the motherboard went bad.After changing the motherboard the system runs fine.

Comment: Struck by lightning? You mean you left your Motherboard out in the rain?

Comment: @GuynamedJon Lol nope. We have a cable broadband connections with external modem, the phone lines here gets frequently subjected to lightning strikes... seen one of my relatives phone line getting charred and molten once, nothing like that here though. however i had to replace the network adapter of the old motherboard twice and the modem too(twice) due to lightning.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing your benchmark results, I see this warning on your "low" result, which raises immediate red flags for me:

> Very high background CPU (62%). High background CPU reduces benchmark
>   accuracy. Find active processes with windows task manager
>   (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC).

The hardware in your system may not be the culprit. This indicates one of the processes was misbehaving. I would do a clean install of your operating environment, or, failing that, I would run [Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/).

As an aside: there's no way on god's green earth your system is running many of the titles you claim it is. I would have you go back and make absolutely sure of the titles you are using as references, because this is likely making many people scratch their heads about what your problem could really be.

Comment: You need to tell us what it was.

Comment: The problem was the motherboard.I didn't change any other parts.Even the windows wasn't reinstalled neither did i made any software changes.

Comment: What specifically was wrong with it?

Comment: lightning struck,would be the possible reason.but i don't know which component inside the motherboard was damaged.

Comment: OK thanks, too bad this wasn't really a helpful Q/A for anyone else then

Comment: a second what is a pcb serial bus? I remember the readings on it were rather errartic when i used speccy from piriform

Comment: Probably nothing related; it is a legacy port used for industrial and networking communications.

Comment: Then can you please tell me,how the processor communicates with all the other components? like where does the pins gets the inputs and what component deals with interfacing between processor and mother board

Comment: As you might expect, there are many different buses that interface between the CPU and the resources on the motherboard. The most important of these are normally called the North and South Bridges, which do everything from address RAM to provide onboard graphics depending on the model. However, many modern designs have begun to integrate these with the CPU itself. Since your computer is very old, it still has both on the motherboard; you can usually find them under a heatsink to the south of the CPU somewhere.